# WCF Rest Api Datetime JSON Serialization Issue

Tags: javascript, json, angular, wcf, typescript

When i send the Javascript Date type to WCF Method as parameter, serialization problem occurs at the following. (**Whereas they are both working with JSON**).

```
DateTime content '2017-05-04T13:09:11.737Z' does not start with '\/Date(' and end with ')\/' as required for JSON.'.
```

**What is the best way to solve this serialization issue? It seems it may solve with string manipulation but Is there any generic way for all WCF Methods that contains type of `DateTime`? (Client side or Server side)**

This is test Angular Http post

```
this.http.post(myTestDateUrl, JSON.stringify( {date : new Date()} ) , {headers: this.getHeaders()})
     .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );

private getHeaders() {

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return headers;
  }
```

This is WCF Test Method

```
[WebInvoke(
Method = "POST",
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
[OperationContract]
public Stream TestDate(DateTime date)
{
    try
    {
        dynamic result = new { status = "OK"};
        return Send(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        dynamic result = new { status = "ERROR", error = ex.Message };
        return Send(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have handled this problem at client side with following converter.

```
export class DateConverter{

    static convertToWCFFormat(date:Date):string{
        return "\/Date(" + date.getTime()+date.getTimezoneOffset() + ")\/";
    }

     static convertToWCFFormatFromStr(date:string):string{
         let _date=new Date(date);
        return "\/Date(" + _date.getTime()+_date.getTimezoneOffset() + ")\/";
    }

    static converToISOFormat(dateStr:string):Date{
        return new Date(parseInt(dateStr.substr(6)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i suggest use ISO 8601 format according [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format?noredirect=1&lq=1):

> ```
> There is no right format; The JSON specification does not specify a format for exchanging dates which is why there are so many different
> ```
>
> ways to do it.
>
> ```
> The best format is arguably a date represented in 8601 format; it is a well known and widely used format and can be handled across many
> ```
>
> different languages, making it very well suited for interoperability.
>   If you have control over the generated json, for example, you provide
>   data to other systems in json format, choosing 8601 as the date
>   interchange format is a good choice.

so you can create something like this:

```
    public Stream TestDate(string date)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime d;
            DateTime.TryParseExact(date, @"yyyy-MM-dd\THH:mm:ss\Z", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out d);
            dynamic result = new { status = "OK" };
            return Send(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            dynamic result = new { status = "ERROR", error = ex.Message };
            return Send(result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was looking for to change WCF default datetime serializer settings in Global.asax file but i couldnt find a way. Actually it should be exist like Web API. This link shows for Web API how to change DateTime Converter. https://himanshudesai.wordpress.com/2013/01/31/web-apihow-to-change-default-serializer-settings/

Comment: dear @BlackEagle. I'm using wcf for about 3 years. and i assure you there is no proper way(like web API) to do such things. here you can read more about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18511147/change-default-date-serialization-in-wcf