# Setting a dateTime with only two characters as milliseconds

Tags: c#, date, wcf

I have a WCF webservice I use to set some date using the following code :

```
foo.StartDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Unfortunately, at the output of the WCF webservice, the date is the following :

```
<a:startDateTime>2019-01-30T08:54:13.698Z</a:startDateTime>
```

The issue is that the millisecond part must be on 2 characters only because our middleware can process only date like that. I know it's valid [ISO 8601](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime) but still.

How is it possible to set the date that will be in the response of the WS with only two characters ?

Comment: It has a WSDL impact not desired if possible

Comment: what is StartDateTime declared as?

Comment: Have you looked here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-web-http-formatting

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27860910/2557128) combined with the mask `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.ffK` should be what you need.