# Modifiy JSON Date time object format

Tags: c#, json, datetime

Hi I am writing a JSON webservice which returns DateTime.

It is returning the date time in EPOCH format. Is it possible to modify the JSON date format it returns.

Code snippet

```
  [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITMAppServices
    {
          [OperationContract]
          [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Test",
          RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
          ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

        DateTime GetData();

    }
```

Actual implementaiton

```
public class TMAppServices : ITMAppServices
 {
     public DateTime GetData()
     {
          return DateTime.Now;
     }
 }
```

i am simply returning datetime.now in C#

Output in EPOCH format :

"/Date(1413399311687+0300)/"

i want output in same format returned by C#
Or if I get datetime from SQL

Comment: `return DateTime.Now;` is returning date in `EPOCH` format ?

Comment: Yes.Its actually a JSON webservice..
When i am running the service this way http://localhost:64964/TMAppServices.svc/Test it returns "\/Date(1413403048647+0300)\/"

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're writing a WCF service.  By default, WCF uses the [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) for JSON serialization - which uses this format.

You should consider either [replacing it with JSON.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659451/replace-default-json-serializer-in-wcf-4-to-json-net) - or preferably, writing your service with [ASP.Net WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api) instead - which already uses [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json).

JSON.Net will (by default) use the [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) serialization format.  This is the preferred format for sending dates over the wire, especially in JSON.  For example, `"2014-10-15T21:54:00-07:00"`.

You should *not* use `DD MM YYYY` format, as JSON is intended to be machine readable.  If a machine with `MM DD YYYY` culture attempts to read the string, it could misinterpret the value.  For example, "1/2/2014" can be read as either January 2nd, or February 1st.

As an aside - you should probably consider using the `DateTimeOffset` type in .NET instead of `DateTime`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My intention was not get in the DD MM YY format. Edited my post. will try JSON.Net