# Serializing TypeBuilder Lists

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I'm creating a WCF Web Service.

I am trying to create a Type based on the information coming back from the database, build a List of the Type with the data, and send that back.

However, I am getting a

> Type 'MyDynamicType' with data contract name 'MyDynamicType:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.
>    error in the trace viewer.

Researching the exception. It recommends adding the type to the `[KnownTypes(Type)]`. How would I do this with a Type created this way?

The Type Builder class code is from 
[How to dynamically create a class in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862226/dynamically-create-a-class-in-c-sharp) with very minor modifications. (i.e. separating creating the type and instance creation.)

Web Service Endpoint

```
   [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            UriTemplate = "/DB/{Q}")]
        List<object> DB(string Q);
```

Web Service Endpoint Code

```
public List<object> DB(string Q)
    {
        List<object> rows = DLL.DB.RunQuery(IQueries.LoadQuery(Q));
        return rows;
    }
```

Run Query Method

```
public static List<object> RunQuery(string query)
        {            
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandText = query;
                    connection.Open();
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        da.Fill(dt);

                        Dictionary<string, Type> columns = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
                        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                        {
                            columns.Add(dc.ColumnName, dc.DataType);
                        }
                        Type customType = MyTypeBuilder.CreateNewObject(columns);                                                
                        List <object> rows = new List<object>();

                        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            List<object> row = new List<object>();
                            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                            {
                                object customInstance = MyTypeBuilder.CreateObjectInstance(customType);
                                PropertyInfo pi = customType.GetProperty(col.ColumnName);
                                pi.SetValue(customInstance, dr[col]);
                                row.Add(customInstance);                                
                            }
                            rows.Add(row);
                        }
                        return rows;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

My Type Builder

```
public class MyTypeBuilder
{        
    public static object CreateObjectInstance(Type myType)
    {
        var myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
        return myObject;
    }
    public static Type CreateNewObject(Dictionary<string,Type> values)
    {
        var myType = CompileResultType(values);            
        return myType;
    }
    public static Type CompileResultType(Dictionary<string, Type> values)
    {
        TypeBuilder tb = GetTypeBuilder();
        ConstructorBuilder constructor = tb.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName);

        // NOTE: assuming your list contains Field objects with fields FieldName(string) and FieldType(Type)
        foreach (var field in values)
            CreateProperty(tb, field.Key, field.Value);

        Type objectType = tb.CreateType();
        return objectType;
    }

    private static TypeBuilder GetTypeBuilder()
    {
        var typeSignature = "MyDynamicType";
        var an = new AssemblyName(typeSignature);
        AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(an, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MainModule");
        TypeBuilder tb = moduleBuilder.DefineType(typeSignature
                            , TypeAttributes.Public |
                            TypeAttributes.Class |
                            TypeAttributes.AutoClass |
                            TypeAttributes.AnsiClass |
                            TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit |
                            TypeAttributes.AutoLayout |
                            TypeAttributes.Serializable
                            , null);

        return tb;
    }
    private static void CreateProperty(TypeBuilder tb, string propertyName, Type propertyType)
    {
        FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = tb.DefineField("_" + propertyName, propertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);

        PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = tb.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, null);
        MethodBuilder getPropMthdBldr = tb.DefineMethod("get_" + propertyName, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);
        ILGenerator getIl = getPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();

        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        MethodBuilder setPropMthdBldr =
            tb.DefineMethod("set_" + propertyName,
              MethodAttributes.Public |
              MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
              MethodAttributes.HideBySig,
              null, new[] { propertyType });

        ILGenerator setIl = setPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
        Label modifyProperty = setIl.DefineLabel();
        Label exitSet = setIl.DefineLabel();

        setIl.MarkLabel(modifyProperty);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);

        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
        setIl.MarkLabel(exitSet);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getPropMthdBldr);
        propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setPropMthdBldr);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Currently your question is not reproducible. Please add more options to your question so that it can be reproducible for someone to test your question and reproduce the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what else I can add without just putting in the source code. The Web Service is extremely basic. The query is simply "SELECT * FROM table". And the dynamic type is on the linked page. I will put in the snippets of code that lead up to it. and hope that helps

Comment: Please add the `TypeBuilder` class code with your minor modifications in your question also.

Comment: How will it be used on client side?

Comment: The data is expected to be returned in JSON format. User is to deal with it how they want to.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a base class that all of your dynamic types inherit from. Then you could have the base class as the one that you put in the knownTypes decorator.

Comment: Good Idea, I'm still learning the TypeBuilder Code. I believe I have been able to set the parent, but so far, still no luck. Same exception.

Comment: You don't need that decorator in WebApi. Consider switching if that is an option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some simple code to get you started,

```
[KnownType(typeof(YourSpecialObject))]
    [DataContract]
    public abstract class BusinessObjectInfo
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public Byte[] Version { get; set; }

    }
```

Now your special object

```
[DataContract]
    public class YourSpecialObject: BusinessObjectInfo
```

Now your WCF should resolve the KnownTypes. As for a way to learn this, Zombie Explorer will have plenty of information in regards to IOC/WCF/PRISM for .NET
Here is a link to the rather thorough example of WCF, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/474212/Zombie-Explorer-An-n-tier-application-from-top-to

Comment: My problem is that I cant or don't now how to add the Decorators to the Generated Type. And at compile, the Type doesn't exist. So putting the [KnownType] on the parent for the child wont work, because it doesn't exist.

Comment: Learning KnownTypes with ExpandoObject should cover what you need to do about serializing unknown types at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it in a completely different and much more easier way. My solutions is based on the following reasoning:

1. Your dynamic type i.e. `MyDynamicType` is created based on the data
   table structure **->**
2. Instances of `MyDynamicType` are actually rows. **->**
3. Instances of `MyDynamicType` are actually key/value collections. **->**
4. You don't have to to create a dynamic type `MyDynamicType`. It would be enough to use a simple dictionary. Keys in this dictionary will be names of columns and values will correspond to cells (values of columns).

As far as I know WCF uses `DataContractJsonSerializer` to serialize data into JSON format and I'm pretty sure that it handles dictionaries correctly. Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559991/any-way-to-make-datacontractjsonserializer-serialize-dictionaries-properly) article.

You can also use another serializer instead a default one, for example Newtonsoft Json.Net serializer. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153628/replace-wcf-built-in-javascriptserializer-with-newtonsoft-json-net-json-serializ) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659451/replace-default-json-serializer-in-wcf-4-to-json-net) question.

Finally, why do you actually use WCF to create REST like API? I think that WebApi is much more easier to use unless you have some specific reasons to use WCF.

Comment: This is almost what I came back to. Most of the reason I wanted to turn the data into a class, so that the JSON it returned would be formatted nicely. Dictionary's by default get handled into a list i.e. {key:'a', value:'b'} for each of the value. I will make an unchecked answer to explain what I did.

Comment: As to fomatting. Objects are serialized as dictionaries in JSON so there should be no difference.

Answer (score 0):

So unfortunately, even with all the great information given to me by everyone here, I was unable to actually get the TypeBuilder to work properly.

However, the reason I was trying to use the TypeBuilder was because my Data was not formatting into JSON as I would have liked it to. It was returning as

> { key : dataname, value : value }

When what I really wanted was

> { dataname : value }

Having done a Web Service with JSON and some other experiences. I know that a Type would conform with this layout. Unfortunately the data is unknown and can change on the fly and the web service had to deal with that (Unfortunate Requirement).

Even though I was unable to get the TypeBuilder to work how I wanted it to. I was able to get the desired result using Newtonsoft.Json and serializing the data from a Dictionary before the server then tried to serialize it for me.

Thanks to everyone for helping. I learnt some interesting and awesome new things that I am likely to use in other projects.

Thanks